# How to add image view in collapsingToolbar layout title?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this collapsingToolbar layout

[image]

I just want to add "rupee" symbol before "6.45" .

But i don't know how to add this image, please help me with that.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".Ads.AdsHomeActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collaps_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/coll_balance_ll"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="top|center"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_wallet_white"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    />

               <!-- <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_india_rupee_white"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:paddingTop="2dp"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="20"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>-->

            </LinearLayout>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_ads_home" />

    <!--<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />-->

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/ads_home_banner_adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

this is my xml file.

Someone says to add imageView i have already tried but it don't appear in front of `6.45` , it's appear in background like this wallet image.

Comment: put layout.xml here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

1.Direct in XML:

```
android:text="\u20B9 25"
```

2.Programmatically in JAVA file

```
samp_txt.setText("Price : \u20B9"+" 20.25");
```

ho here we use `\u20B9` unicode to print rupees symbol.